# Text Not Appearing in the Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to show the div named "Content" when user hovers over an image map I have created. Moreover, I have also tried making it's `Visibility` property `Hidden` and change it to `Show` when user hovers over the map but it didn't work out that well.

Furthermore, I have one more div called "Members" that I want to keep on right side of the image.

Fiddling with the properties is causing the text to disappear all of a sudden. Why is it happen & how can I solve it?

Here's my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style>
            #pipelines {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-top: auto;
                margin-bottom: auto;
                float:left;

            }
            #content {
                font-family: Helvetica Neue;
                border: solid;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right:10px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                background-color: white;
                position: relative;
                width: 20%;
                height: 0;
                padding-bottom: 20%;

            }
            hr{
                background-color:#000;
            }
            h4{padding-bottom:0px;
            padding-top:0px;}
            #members{
                float:right;
                position:relative;
            }

        </style>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Pipeline</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="pipelines">
            <img src="2D_Pipeline.jpg" usemap="#Map" border="0"/>
            <map name="Map" id="Map">
              <area shape="rect" coords="155,70,267,96" href="#" alt="Writers" />
            </map>


        </div>
        <div id="members"><h1>Mem</h1></div>
        <div id="content">
            <h4></h4>
            <hr />
            John Howard
        </div>
        <script>

            $("#Map").on('mouseenter', function(e) {
                //$("#content").css("visibility", "show");
                $("#content").stop().show();
                $("#content").offset({
                    left : e.pageX,
                    top : e.pageY
                });
                var alt_script = $("area").attr("alt");
                $("#content h4").html(alt_script);
            });

            $("#content").on('mouseenter', function(e) {
                //$("#content").css("visibility", "show");
                $("#content").stop().show();

            });

            $("#Map").on('mouseleave', function(e) {
                $("#content").stop().delay(500).hide();
            });

            $("#content").on('mouseleave', function(e) {
                $("#content").stop().delay(500).hide();
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the image I am using: http://imgur.com/eJK42SZ :)

Answer (score 1):

`delay()` doesn't work with `hide()` or `show()` unless you provide an easing/animation queue.

`delay()` only queues the next animation, and since methods like `hide()` are instant (and not animations), they are not on the queue, and thus not delayed.

What you can do

`var timer = setTimeout(function() { $('#id').hide(); }, 500);`

And use `clearTimeout(timer);` to prevent the function from executing.

Comment: So basically, I should remove the .delay()?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you want, or am I missing something?

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/3NShg/3/ (ctrl+shift+enter to see it in a browser window)

```
$("#pipelines")
.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    //    setTimeout here if you want and change fadeIn to show();
    $('#content').fadeIn(400);
})
.on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    $('#content').fadeOut(400)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this weird issue by using `Overflow: Hidden` & tweaking other properties as well.

To those who answered, thanks for the help guys. :)